# How to send an email when laptop battery is low?

Tags: laptop, scripts, power-management, email

Is it possible to send an email to myself when the laptop is on low battery power?

I'm always online with my Android phone, but not always in front of the laptop, and sometimes I'm missing the warning.

Perhaps a Python or Bash script?

Comment: Interesting, haven't tried that, but i guess the answer is `Yes`. http://masnun.com/2010/09/01/python-script-to-monitor-laptop-battery-charge-ubuntulinux-mint.html, found this on googling. Just add mail sending function and your good to go.

Comment: Many thanks. Now i'm gonna search how to send mail using python. If/when i suceed, i'll post it back here.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Ubuntu software called [**Cuttlefish**](https://launchpad.net/cuttlefish) which enables you to create some tasks when some events occur on your computer. Perhaps you may create a task which sends you an email when the battery is low.

You can install it by writing it in a terminal : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noneed4anick/cuttlefish && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cuttlefish`.